# Silverlight SelectedRow styling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, datagrid

I had an issue changing the foreground color for selected items on Datagrids.

I found a fix that works, but it is expensive when using Datagrids with a lot of items/data and it also complicates the design tree a bit more.

This is my Coding:

```
...<VisualState x:Name="NormalSelected">
     <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
           <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Yellow"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      </Storyboard>
</VisualState>...
```

...

```
...<ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Foreground="Green">
          <sdk:DataGridCellsPresenter x:Name="CellsPresenter" Grid.Column="1" sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True"/>
   </ContentControl>...
```

This is the only way I could think of doing it in XAML. I don't know if there are any other ways of doing it in xaml rather than rapping the CellPresenter with a control everytime?

Comment: What exactly does "expensive" mean? And how many rows x columns  does your `DataGrid` have? Honestly I don't see any discernible problem. Two suggestions: 1) if all you want is to change `Foreground` color, then you should simply use `ColorAnimation`; 2) I would move `Grid.Column=1` from `DataGridCellPresenter` to `ContentControl`, now that the latter contains the former.

Comment: By Expensive I mean expensive in performance. Maybe not in a grid of 10 or 50 items, but in a grid with 100s - 1000s of rows it can get a bit rough. It does work wrapping it with the ContentControl but as I said it is not ideal for large grids. @jsanalytics

Comment: i didn't experience any performance issues in a 1000 rows x 5 columns datagrid. Did you try my 2 suggestions to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: There will not be any performance issues no. But there will be a difference in execution time. Maybe I should choose my words better. but I did a test to see how fast the coding runs when loading 9000 rows. With the wrapper it average about 50ms - 100ms more than without the wrapper. It is not a big issue no but it is always best to take the fastest option. @jsanalytics